# HTML repetition using HTML5 with mobilejquery data-role=page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am writing HTML5/CSS pages using jQuery mobile.  I am stuck with the HTML code repetition in my pages.

Is there a similar Master pages concept as in (asp.net) which I can implement with HTML5 pages and mobile jQuery(data-role="page")?

Comment: I am familiar with jQuery mobile but not familiar with the concept of "Master Pages" as in ASP.net.  Can you elaborate further on the function?

Comment: Master pages in the asp.net are used to coomanise the html used in differtent pages... "write once use many time" by referring that common code.hope u get the concept of Master pages.

Comment: Maybe you are talking about jQuery UI widgets?  A jQuery UI widget is a reusable component that encapsulates HTML and code.

Comment: what is happening is that in different pages(datarole=page) in mobile jquery i have to repeat the same html code what i want to show on header.

Comment: Sorry...i have just started with the jquery mobile so i have no idea about jquery widgets.are u suggesting me to look for jquery mobile for my issue?

Comment: I get the impression that you are trying to encapsulate code into re-usable components so that you don't have to recode them over and over.   I think that the use of a jQuery UI widget would be one way to achieve that goal.

Comment: absolutly...i will look at UI widgets..give me some time.hope it will be helpful.Thank you so much.

Comment: Have a look at external toolbars: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/toolbar-external/  This allows you to use the same header and footer on multiple pages.